# WPF : Getting the sender of UserControl

Tags: wpf, mvvm, sender

I am having WPF MVVM application. I am having UserControl.
From few places in application I am calling this UserControl. User Control contains Image which show camera stream and back button.

The problem is when I click "Back" in UserControl I would like to know who called it.

Does anyone know how I can get sender?

Comment: show code where you click `Back` button.

Comment: When you call the `UserControl` pass the `sender` to the `UserControl constructor`.

Comment: Abin Mathew perfect thanks :)

Comment: The question is a bit contradicting... you say it's an MVVM application, but you use and call UserControl directly, which isn't very MVVM. Reconsider your tags or clarify your question

Comment: @Tseng I for one am interested in the answer in the case of a MVVM architecture.